# jQuery phone number format check without validation plug-in

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, format, phone-number

Does anyone know how to wring a simple US format phone number checker without using the validation plugin?

So far I have something like this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
if($(this).hasClass('phoneNum')) {
    var phone_number = $(this.value).replace(/\s+/g, ''); 
    if(phone_number.length > 9 && phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/)) {
        //..........do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915650/jquery-validation-of-nanp-phone-numbers?rq=1?

Comment: Austin, this bin must be related http://pastebin.com/RGAEresD  and if it is yours, include it with your question. If it is not from you, we have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MadTurki you were right but j08691 thank you for directing me to a post that answers this question better.  I ended up going with the following and it works great!

```
if($(this).hasClass('phoneNum')){
            var error = 1;
            var hasError = false;
            var $this = $(this);
            var regex1 = /^([2-9]{1}\d{2})([2-9]{1}\d{2})\d{4}$/;
            phone = $(this).val();
            phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');        
            if(!regex1.test(phone)){
                isValid = false;
                $this.css('background-color','#FF7575');
            }   
            else{
                area = phone.substring(0,3);
                prefix = phone.substring(3,6);
                line = phone.substring(6);
                $this.val('(' + area + ') ' + prefix + '-' + line);
                $this.css('background-color','#A7E9A7');    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is:

```
var phone_number = $(this.value).replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Should be:

```
var phone_number = $(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

There may be another issue, but this jumps out to me immediately.